# How do I update a row of data using c# and sql

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-update

I'm trying to update an image field where the id is equal to the row selected.

I've tried using the below code

```
String query = "UPDATE ArticlesTBL SET ArticleImg = VALUE (@ArticleImg) WHERE ArticleID = VALUE (@id)";              
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticleImg", "UploadedUserFiles/" + FileUpdate.FileName);
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", ThisID));

myinfo.Text = query;
```

But I don't know where to place commas, brackets etc in the query string. I have a text box outputting my command and it shows that i'm using UPDATE ArticlesTBL SET ArticleImg = @ArticleImg WHERE ArticleID = @id But I'm not actually accessing the parameters. So, how do I access these parameters? Thanks

Comment: You get your `@id` parameter in your `TextBox`? You don't need to use `VALUE` by the way.

Comment: Yes

TextBox RecordID = editarticle.EditItem.FindControl("ArticleIDTextBox") as TextBox;
        Int32 ThisID = Convert.ToInt32(RecordID.Text);

Comment: What are the types of `ArticleID` and `ArticleImg` columns?

Comment: ID is an int and img is a string

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for your update statement is

```
String query = @"UPDATE ArticlesTBL 
                 SET ArticleImg = @ArticleImg 
                 WHERE ArticleID = @id";
```

And to avoid confusion with the constructor of an SqlParameter that accepts a SqlDbType and an Object I suggest to use AddWithValue also for the ID

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticleImg", "UploadedUserFiles/" + FileUpdate.FileName);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ThisID);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Of course, the command needs to be executed after you have prepared the command text, added its parameters and associated the connection

Comment: I'm still getting the same message in my info textbox and the table isn't updated. I don't think it is recognising the parameters

Comment: Did you execute the command? I mean, do you call myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()?

Comment: Yeah I did. By trying this instead:
                String query = "UPDATE ArticlesTBL SET ArticleImg = '" + newimg + "' WHERE ArticleID ='" + ThisID +"'";   
I now get the message UPDATE ArticlesTBL SET ArticleImg = 'UploadedUserFiles/Lighthouse.jpg' WHERE ArticleID ='53' returned, which is progress but it doesn't update my table

Comment: What is your connectionstring and what is your user interface (WinForms, ASP.NET)?

Comment: I also suggest to use the debugger. Put a breakpoint at the entry line of this code and check if your variable values are correct before the execute

Comment: It's ASP.NET.

String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectAntiFrack"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
myConnection.Open();
String newimg = "UploadedUserFiles/";
newimg += imgName;
String query = "UPDATE ArticlesTBL SET ArticleImg = '" + newimg + "' WHERE ArticleID ='" + ThisID +"'";   
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);              
editarticle.Visible = false;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConnection.Close();

Comment: It seems all OK from here. The only thing that could be wrong is the extraction of the value for the ID parameter. If this is wrong the query doesn't find anything to update. Again, try with the debugger to check the value of this field.

Comment: Yeah I realised that my ID was wrong further up the page so I wasn't changing the table row I thought I was. All sorted now though!